# How to add horizontal lines showing means for all groups in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to place horizontal lines with the group means on a plot without creating the summary data set ahead of time? I know this works, but I feel there must be a way to do this with just `ggplot2`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
X <- data_frame(
  x = rep(1:5, 3),
  y = c(rnorm(5, 5, 0.5),
        rnorm(5, 3, 0.3),
        rnorm(5, 4, 0.7)),
  grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 5))

X.mean <- X %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarize(y = mean(y))

X %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = grp)) +
  geom_point(shape = 19) +
  geom_hline(data = X.mean, aes(group = grp, yintercept = y, color = grp)) +
  background_grid()
```

[image: grouped mean lines]

Comment: Try `stat_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~1)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

```
ggplot(X, aes(x = x, y = y, color = grp)) +
  geom_point(shape = 19) +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~1, se=FALSE)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

So this applies a linear model with only the constant term, which returns the mean. Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985661/geom-abline-does-not-seem-to-respect-groups-in-facet-grid-ggplot2) for the basic idea.

*Edit*: Response to OP's very clever suggestion.

It looks like you *can* use quantile regression to generate the medians!

```
library(quantreg)
ggplot(X, aes(x = x, y = y, color = grp)) +
  geom_point(shape = 19) +
  stat_smooth(method="rq", formula=y~1, se=FALSE)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The basic requirement for `stat_smooth(method=..., ...)` is that the method returns an object for which there is a `predict(...)` method. So here `rq(...)` returns an `rq` object and there is a `predict.rq(...)` method. You can get into trouble using `se=TRUE` sometimes as not all predict methods return standard errors of the estimates.

Comment: What if I want to fit a median?

Comment: Could I use `stat_smooth` with the `quantreg` package?

Comment: Very clever idea! Yes, it does look like that works. See my edits.