# ggplot Find sum of all groups and plot as line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data that looks like this

```
Group   x    y
 A      2    30
 B      2    21
 C      2    22
 A      3    15
 B      3    18
 C      3    5   
 A      4    14
 B      4    29
 C      4    46
```

And create a chart with:

```
gg <- ggplot(mydata,
         aes(x=x, y=y, fill=Group, group=Group))+
      geom_line(data =mydata,
        aes(x=x, y=y,colour=Group),
        stat="identity",
        size=1.5)
plot(gg)
```

I'm trying to add a fourth line that has the sum of A+B+C at every X. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429287/ggplot2-add-line-for-sum-of-group-values-at-each-x) but it adds 5 lines, not one with a sum. I want a line that would be `y=73` when `x=2`, `y=38` when `x=3`, and `y=89` when `x=4`.

Code:

```
Group <- c("A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C")
x <- c(2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
y <- c(30,21,22,15,18,5,14,29,46) 
mydata <- data.frame(Group,x,y)



gg <- ggplot(mydata,
         aes(x=x, y=y, fill=Group, group=Group))+
      geom_line(data =mydata,
        aes(x=x, y=y,colour=Group),
        stat="identity",
        size=1.5)
plot(gg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to generate a variable that sums all values of `y` by `x` via `dplyr`'s `group_by` and `mutate`-functions. You can then generate your plot and add a second line geom that will show the `x`-specific sums.

```
library(tidyverse)    

mydata %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(sum.y = sum(y)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, color=Group))+
  geom_line(size=1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = sum.y), color = "black")
```

Note that I changed your code by removing redundant code in the aesthetics, `stat = "identity"` in `geom_line` and all of the `data = mydata` specifications. These are simply not necessary.

[image]

Comment: My `ggplot` specifications are within a `for(i in seq_along(list))` loop that runs through a list of df. Do I just stick the code within the loop as normal?

Comment: What do you mean by 'as normal'? You probably need to get rid of the pipes (`%>%`) and  specify `data = mydata` once in the main ggplot command line. The rest is still redundant.